# Results from cursor into view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way to fetch values from cursor into a view?

I have to create procedure, that calculates hash values of all procedures in database and it should put it into a view.

My code so far:

```
DECLARE Cur_Procedures CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT name
FROM sys.procedures
OPEN Cur_Procedures

FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_Procedures INTO @SpName                                                         

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN   

    SET @SpDefinition = (SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID(@SpName )))
    SET @HashedVal = dbo.fnHashBytes('SHA1', CAST(ISNULL(@SpDefinition,'') AS VARBINARY(MAX)))

    --now I should store @HashedVal somewhere

    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_Procedures INTO @SpName
END
CLOSE Cur_Procedures
DEALLOCATE Cur_Procedures
--and now I should put it into view.
```

I tried to store it in `#TempTable`, and then create view, but it wont work like that.

Am I able to do this without creating table? I'd like to avoid solid tables if it is possible.

Comment: Views should be inline, they can't contain multiple queries/statements. Anyway, you can place this logic into multi-statement user defined table function instead of view.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Can you show me some example or something?

Comment: There is no need for a cursor here, why are you using one?

Comment: I removed the cursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without cursor (row by row processing should be avoided when possible):

```
SELECT [name] = OBJECT_NAME(object_id),
       [hash] = HASHBYTES('SHA1' ,[definition])
FROM sys.sql_modules;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/424977)**</kbd>

You can wrap it with `VIEW` and change `HASHBYTES` to `dbo.fnHashBytes` if needed.

---

Using system views:

```
SELECT name, HASHBYTES('SHA1', sm.[definition] )
FROM sys.procedures sp
JOIN sys.sql_modules sm
  ON sp.object_id = sm.object_id;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/424983)**</kbd>

Keep in mind that [`sql_modules`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx):

> **The visibility of the metadata in catalog views is limited to
>   securables that a user either owns or on which the user has been
>   granted some permission.** For more information, see Metadata Visibility
>   Configuration.
>
> **NULL = Encrypted**

Comment: Does `sm.[definition]` return full text of procedure's body?

Comment: According to [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx) it returns `nvarchar(max)`. I guess you are refering to case when SSMS cannot display it correctly. **[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/424997)**